# Inversing a twodimensional array in python

Tags: python, arrays, reverse

I have an array a, which is twodimensional. A contains objects which also contain objects.
I want to make sure that a[1,1] becomes a[n,n], a[2,1] becomes a[n-1,n], a[2,2] becomes a[n-1][n-1] etc.
I wrote the following code to do this:

```
tempArray = copy(self.topArea)
for y in range(0,len(tempArray)):
    for x in range(0,len(tempArray[y])):
        self.topArea[y][x] = tempArray[len(tempArray)-1-y][len(tempArray[y])-1-x]
```

But this achieves litteraly nothing. Deepcopying also does not help: the array does not get inverted.

How can I invert it?

Comment: Is this a `numpy` array, or are you using the wrong word for a `list`?

Comment: Also note that iterating by index is a terrible idea in Python - it is slow, inefficient, inflexible and hard to read. Python is designed to iterate by value, not index.

Comment: Can you give a little better definition of `inversing`?  At first, I answered showing how to take the transpose, but now I think that isn't what you want ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want something like:

```
tempArray = [list(reversed(x)) for x in reversed(self.topArea)]
```

If everything is lists, you could also do:

```
tempArray = [x[::-1] for x in reversed(self.topArea)]
```

for a possible speed boost.

Comment: `tempArray = [x[::-1] for x in self.topArea[::-1]]` ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux `reversed` is memory efficient as it returns an iterator.

Comment: Also, presumably, `reversed` should work for more objects.  I'm not sure if I've found that to be true in actual practice, but any sequence can be reversed (including `xrange` which you can't slice)